# Unfortunate title length limitation when performing dead link maintenance

Tags: support, hyperlinks, titles, minor-edits

[This question about disc projections](https://mathoverflow.net/q/39127/317841) has a link to an animation of a Reuleaux triangle spinning inside a square.

"That sounds cool, I want to see what that looks like!", I thought.

Unfortunately, the link was dead, but through the internet archive I was able to track down the original animation, and find a modern location for it. (It can be found here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Reuleaux_triangle_Animation.gif)

Succeeding in finding the animation, I thought I could make a quick edit to the post updating the dead link.

Unfortunately, when submitting my edit, the following appeared:

[image: error message]

[image: error: title too long]

So it appears that some validation limits have changed since the question was originally posted, making it impossible for me to update the link without shortening the title (which would be very intrusive).

What's the best course of action to take in this case?

Comment: I took the liberty of implementing your edit (the Reuleaux triangle spinning inside a square) with a slightly shortened title (149 characters).

Answer (score 3):

If things are actually as you say they are, I don't think anyone could object to you cutting the second part of the title and then pasting it at the start of the body.

Comment: I would find it preferable to keep the second part as the title, and put the first part in the post body.

Comment: @Joel, no objections from me.

Comment: I tried a work around, slight edits to the title to bring it back to 150 characters (still keeping both parts).